# Showing a set is compact in a different $\mathbb{R}^2$ topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I have the following problem: The set $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a topology T for which the closed sets are the empty set and the
finite unions of vector subspaces. Let X denote the set $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}$ with the subspace topology
induced by T . By considering the subspace topology on $S_1$
 ⊂ $\mathbb{R}^2$, or otherwise, show that X is compact.

Is it valid to say: The open sets are just $\mathbb{R}^2$- {finite unions of vector spaces}. So take an open cover, pick an arbitrary element in the cover. Then this covers all but a finite union of vector subspaces, which can then be covered by a finite number of open sets in the cover.

I'm doubtful, since the answer seems too short for the context the question is in, and doesn't use the hint given.

Comment: "which can then be covered by a finite number of open sets in the cover" needs more discussion.

Comment: well say you have vector subspaces $V_i$ for i=1,...,n not covered by the first open set. Then some open sets in the cover $U_i$ have $V_i$ ⊂ $U_i$. So then the union of $V_i$ plus the first set covers X?

Comment: That's the basic idea, but I think you need a little more discussion (a sentence should suffice) to defend the claim that $V_i$ lies entirely in some $U_i$.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean, I would write more down but was just sketching an argument . Any idea what the intended way of doing the question would be? I thought about perhaps showing X was homeomorphic to $S_1$ but didnt get very far

Comment: Your way is fine. Not every problem is hard!

Comment: When you write a proof, to be sure it's acceptable, you should imagine an audience of peers, rather than the professor. With that assumption, you should try to anticipate possible points of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observation 1: $S^1$ in the usual topology is compact. So it is also compact in this weaker topology (vector subspaces are already usual-closed, so open sets in this topology are usual-open sets). Any open cover in the weaker topology is one in the usual topology etc.

Observation 2: if two vector subspaces intersect in $X$, they also intersect in $S^1$: a have a *non-zero* (because $0 \notin X$) vector $v \in V_1 \cap V_2$, then $\frac{1}{\|v\|}\cdot v \in V_1 \cap V_2 \cap S^1$. This in fact holds for any intersection of vector subspaces in $X$.

From 2 follows that a family of closed sets in $X$ has the FIP iff its intersections with $S^1$ have the FIP there.

Now apply the closed sets (or FIP family) formulation of compactness to see $X$ is compact.